# selenium python: element not intreractable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, automation-testing

The problem is when I am clicking the first name field, the click is working, but when I am sending the text to the field, it is showing me the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

s = Service("C:/Users/TUL/Desktop/cd/cd.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.universityliving.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/a[1]/div/div/div').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slick-slide slick-active slick-current']//div//img[@alt='Urbanest Carlton Melbourne']").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/p').click()
driver.current_window_handle

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="enquiryForm"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="enquiryForm"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label').send_keys('h')
time.sleep(3)
```

What I am expecting is, if the field is clickable then it must be text acceptable also.